# Почему переменная сохраняет данное выражение?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int k = 1, j = 2, l=0,o;
    o = k + j || l++;
}
```

Прошелся отладчиком, но таки не понял, почему переменная `о` сохраняет значение 1?

Comment: Что значит "сохраняет"? У вас изначально `o` вообще не имеет никакого определенного значения. Как она может его "сохранять"?

Answer (score 4):

Выражение `(k + j) || (l++)` является логическим выражением с результатом `true`. При приведении к типу `int` значение `true` превращается в значение `1`. Его вы и видите.

Выражение имеет результат `true` уже потому, что слева от оператора `||` стоит ненулевое значение `k + j`. Ненулевые целые значения в логическом контексте выступают в роли `true`. Так как левый операнд `||` является `true`, то и результат является `true`. Правый операнд `||` при этом даже не будет вычисляться, т.е. `l` сохранит значение `0`.

Comment: Это со скобочками, разве без них не || выполнится первее +?